# Why Gravitational Potential is same In Both these cases?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, newtonian-gravity, work, potential-energy

We usually choose Reference point as Infinity which is Linear to the Points

[image]

and by this way we gat work done as both force and displacement are in the same direction as well as in the same line which results in change in potential. But in many cases for example, rinf force and displacement from infinty to p does not act in same line

[image]

In case (ii) as well potential at P by dm mass is equl to $-Gdm/a$, though the work done is totally different as force is not in the direction of motion. But still potential in both case i and case ii is same? Why so?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really clear on what you are asking, but Newton's third law says that when two objects exert a force on each other, the two forces must be equal and opposite.  That means that the potential energy associated with that force will be the same for either one, if one is held fixed and the other is moving.